# constructing an nested if excel formula

Tags: excel

I have a scenario where I need to identify a result. Below is a sample excel cells with three columns `Prod Name, Qty and Result`.

```
Prod Name    Qty     Result
abc          10 
zyz          9  
test1        5
```

If the product name is `abc or zyz` and its qty is 10, then I need to add text `Refill` in Column Result.

For any other product. in this case `test1` and its qty is 5, then I need to add the same text `Refill` in Column Result.

Else it will always be `Don't Refill`

Comment: What formula have you tried? What problem have you encountered? As it is, you have given a specification but haven't actually asked a question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND(OR(A1="abc", A1="xyz"), B1=10), AND(AND(A1<>"abc", A1<>"xyz"), B1=5)),
    "Refill",
    "Don't Refill")
```

Comment: `For any other product. in this case test1` I think that there are more than just that one case for `5`

Comment: @ScottCraner Good catch.  You've been staring into spreadsheets for way too long :-)

Comment: I find it relaxing after spending too much time in sql databases all day.  Excel is a little simpler.

Comment: Just an FYI: `OR(A1="abc", A1="xyz")` can be shortened to `OR(A2={"abc","zyz"})` and `AND(AND(A1<>"abc", A1<>"xyz"), B1=5)` to `AND(A2<>{"abc","zyz"},B2=5)` without the need of CSE.

Answer (score 0):

The formula provided by Tim above should work nicely, but if you're looking for VBA approach:

> *(Presuming the data is in a table called Table1 in a sheet called
>   Sheet1)*

```
Private Sub comb_products()

  Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

For Each Rng In tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange


 If ((Rng.Value2 = "abc" Or Rng.Value2 = "zyz") And Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = 10) Then
        Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = "Refill"
 ElseIf ((Rng.Value2 <> "abc" Or Rng.Value2 <> "zyz") And Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = 5) Then
        Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = "Refill"
 Else
        Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = "Don't refill"
 End If

Next Rng

End Sub
```

Result as expected:

[image]